# SXA toolbox missing when editing pages and partial designs

Tags: sxa

Somewhere between upgrading Sitecore/SXA and merging conflicts with the themes, all of a sudden the toolbox does not appear.

What should I verify to get it working again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After working with Adam N. and him pointing me in the right direction I discovered a few things.

1. Confirm that the **Drag and Drop** settings is enabled while in the *Experience Editor*.

[image: Drag and Drop]

2. Confirm that the **Editing Theme** in your site's theme has the BaseLayout themes added and in the right order.

[image: Editing Theme]

3. Take notice that the first Base Theme in the list is for **Editing Theme**. This is an SXA theme that includes the *toolbox.js* required to show the theme.

Now the beautiful toolbox appears!

[image: Toolbox]